# How to protect a base class from causing errors in its subclasses?

Tags: oop, inheritance, language-agnostic, abstract-class

One of the disadvantages of inheritance is that the superclass and its subclasses are very tightly coupled. A lot of resources (e.g. SO) say to compensate for this by being 'cautious' when writing a class that might be subclassed.

Are there any guidelines about what precautions you should take, or testing processes to go through to make sure your base class is safe? Or do you just have to try to predict all potential subclass behavior?

Comment: My guess is that the only way to go is solid design and solid unit tests, following the "generally accepted good practices" (whatever this might mean, but for example encapsulation, designing to the interface, planning ahead). I can't see a silver bullet for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as little as required in the parent classes. If you must do more complex operations then separate them into logical pieces, putting each piece in a different method so that children can override them as appropriate.